# KL-divergence, total variation distance and weak convergence against unbounded functions

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, uniform-integrability

Let $p_n,p$ be absolutely continuous probability measures on $\mathbb R^d$. Suppose they are close w.r.t. Kullback-Leibler divergence:
$$ D_{KL}(p_n|p) \leq \frac{C}{n} \quad\forall\,n\geq1\,.$$
As a consequence they are also close in total variation:
$$ \|p_n-p\|_{TV}^2\leq \frac{2C}{n}\quad\forall\,n\geq1\;.$$
What can we say about the difference
$$ \Big|\int f\,dp_n-\int f\,d p\Big| $$
when $f:\mathbb R^d\to\mathbb R$ is continuous, $\sup_n\int|f|^l dp_n<\infty$ for every $l\geq1$, but $f$ not bounded ?

Comment: If $l>1$, this is immediate since tv convergence implies weak convergence and we conclude with a uniform integrability argument + Skorokhod representation.

Comment: @Snoop can you get an explicit bound on the difference?

Comment: As first impression I would say that a quantitative bound could need more assumptions on $f$

Comment: @Snoop for example?